# AndroidDev: AsyncTask for Stock App - Nothing happening

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am working on a simple app to gather current information on Stock(s). I am applying AsyncTask and I have my GUI built but nothing seems to happen after I type in the stock symbol into my EditText. Any assistance is much appreciated. I have tried googling these topics and looked at docs and tutorials but not sure what I am missing. I am about 2 months into learning android development.

Here is my code:

```
package cornez.com.stockquotes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;
    String symbol;
    TextView symbolText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView nameText, tradePriceText, tradeTimeText, changeText, rangeText;

        symbolText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.symbolText);
        nameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        tradePriceText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tradePriceText);
        tradeTimeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tradeTimeText);
        changeText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.changeText);
        rangeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rangeText);


        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                          KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
                {
                    // actions when "Done" key is pressed

                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });



        editText.requestFocus();
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.
                SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

        getStockInfoTask stockTask = new getStockInfoTask();
        symbol = editText.getText().toString();
        stockTask.execute(symbol);


    }

    //AsyncTask
    private class getStockInfoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Stock>
    {

        protected Stock doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            Stock stock = new Stock(symbol);
            try {
                stock.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return stock;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Stock stock)
        {
            symbolText.setText(stock.getSymbol());
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: I tried to add code for my Stock class in case anyone wanted to see that too but it will not let me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The code inside

   ```
   onEditorAction
   ```

runs in a new thread when the textView receives an action.

2. The code

   ```
   symbol = editText.getText().toString();
   ```

runs sync after the listener is initialized.

So:

```
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                      KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
            {
                // actions when "Done" key is pressed

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

                getStockInfoTask stockTask = new getStockInfoTask();
                symbol = editText.getText().toString();
                stockTask.execute(symbol);

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });



    editText.requestFocus();
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.
            SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```